# Automated file rename - const variable is changing its value?

Tags: c++, string, winapi, variables, std

I'm kind of a noob with the `std` namespace, and I'm writing code that loops through all the jpeg files in a directory and removes any exclamation points.  I'm trying to use `std::string` and `std::vector`.  My problem is that my variable tempname: `const char tempname = (char) *filelist[j].c_str();` changes as the strings in the vector `filelist` changes (which it shouldn't - it is a constant variable. Here is the meat of my WinMain function:

```
std::vector<std::string> filelist;
if (!dirExists(directory)) //checks if a directory exists
{
    CreateDirectory("resized", NULL);
}
std::vector<std::string> filelist = findFiles("*.jpg"); //finds files in its directory with a given extension
int result; //for rename function
for (unsigned int j=0; j< filelist.size(); j++)
{
    std::string::size_type pos = filelist[j].find("!"); //check for exclamation points
    if (std::string::npos != pos) //found one at index "pos" in the string
    {
        switch (MessageBox(window, (LPCSTR)filelist[j].c_str(), "Illegal filename - Rename?", MB_YESNO)) //user input
        {
            case IDYES:
            {
                const char tempname = (char) *filelist[j].c_str(); //the problem
                //attempt to remove the exclamation point
                result = rename(&tempname, filelist[j].erase(pos, 1).c_str());
                if (result == 0)
                    MessageBox(window, "Renamed File", "Information", MB_OK);
                else
                    MessageBox(window, "Error renaming file", "Error", MB_OK);
                break;
            }
            case IDNO:
            {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Assuming the filename contains no more than one exclamation point.  If I defined tempname as a `const char*` this would make sense, because it would be a pointer - tempname's value could change without violating the `const` declaration if the data it pointed to changed.  But taking away the pointer, I'm baffled.

Comment: "const char tempname" is one char

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You realize that your declaration of tempname means that you'll be copying in exactly one character? I'm pretty sure that's not what you wanted.

You probably want to make a copy of the string itself and change the code as follows:

```
            std::string const tempname = filelist[j];
            //attempt to remove the exclamation point
            result = rename(tempname.c_str(), filelist[j].erase(pos, 1).c_str());
```

As to why your supposedly const variable change its value if you manipulate the underlying string, keep in mind that in your original declaration, tempname is a *pointer* to a value and all you said was that the pointer doesn't change its value. Which it didn't, but the pointee did.

Also, when combining c_str with string manipulation you're pretty much entering dangerous territory - have a look at the documentation for c_str [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/c_str/), it clearly states that calling mutating member functions on the string object may invalidate the result of the c_str() call. You have to be careful when mixing std::string with C string idioms.

Answer (score 0):

The code you post has undefined behavior, which means that
anything can happen.  You define a single `char`, `tempname`,
and then pass its address to `rename`.  `rename` requires
a pointer to a `'\0'` terminated string; the only legal one
character string would be an empty string.

If you replace the definition of `tempname` with:

```
char const* tempname = filelist[j].c_str();
```

then you have undefined behavior later; the call to
`filelist[j].erase` invalidates this pointer.  In practice, it
will in fact continue to point to the data in `filelist[j]`
(since in fact, the `erase` will not reallocate, and so 
`tempname` will continue to point to the first character in
`filelist[j]`).

What you probably want is something like:

```
std::string newName( filelist[j] );
newName.erase( std::remove( newName.begin(), newName.end(), '!' ),
               newName.end() );
result = rename( filelist[j].c_str(), newName.c_str() );
filelist[j] = newName;
```